# Binding :src value wih require in v-img

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to dynamically load pictures in my component.

```
:src="getImg(articles[0].photo)"
```

Why am i using getImg method? When i tried to do it like this

```
<v-img src="../../public/Boisko.jpg" contain>
```

I was getting no img, no error.

Here all my attemps. I dont really have an idea what can i be doing wrong.

```
  public getImg(img: string) {
    const path = '../../public/' + img;
    console.log(img); // = 'Boisko.jpg'
    return require(path); // Module not found
    // return require('../../public/' + 'Boisko.jpg'); // Working
    // return require('../../public/Boisko.jpg'); // Working
    // return require('../../public/' + img); // Error Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
    // You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file
  }
```

Comment: You don't need `public`, it's assumed so remove that like it's already included in the path.

Comment: Do you mean to shortcut the path to '../../' + img? If so it doesn`t work. Error: Module not found.

Comment: Your comment about public dir made me thinking about the place where files shoould be located. I changed theirs location into assets directory and it started working? The path has changed from "../../public/' + img" into "../assets/' + img". Was i having some typo that i didnt notice earlier. Or do images have to be in this certain directory?

Comment: Yeah, put them into `assets` and prefer using `@` or `~` (aliases) rather than relative paths `../..`.